# Hyperledger Composerr identity issue : Error - Unexpected token P in JSON at position 0

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

I developed a hyperledger composer application along with angular application with multi user authentication. 
the network admin can issue a identity when creating a new user. Adding a new user function is works properly but when issue a identity, (it also works) but displays the following error.

Unexpected token P in JSON at position 0

Here is the identity object which I passed to the REST API.

const identity = {

'participant': 'org.ucsc.agriblockchain.Stakeholder#'this.Id.value,

'userID': this.username.value,

'options': {}

}

following image shows the REST API part for the identity issue.The response of this request is a downloadable file.

[REST API identity issue method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vR8vJ.png)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Can you please edit your question that no pictures of code are present any more? See also: http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/ or http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode . This might also be interesting: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: hi there, I think there may be a couple of issues: 1) your participant has Stakholder when it should be Stakeholder (per your REST API screenshot). 2) A full example of what you're trying to do is shown [here](https://github.com/caroline-church/collectable-penguin-app/blob/master/src/services/rest.service.ts#L27) so you can compare with something that works.

Comment: @ Paul O'Mahony - thanks for your solutions. According to the example you provided I did my work as shown in https://github.com/caroline-church/collectable-penguin-app/blob/master/src/services/rest.service.ts#L27.  According to line 35 when i   add {responseType: 'blob'} it displays the following error                   
Argument of type '{ responseType: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'RequestOptionsArgs'. Types of property 'responseType' are incompatible. Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'ResponseContentType'. How can i fix it